# Accessing $_SERVER in class method

Tags: php, class, global-variables

This is a really simple question, but I can't find much because I'm probably not phrasing something correctly.

Do I have to declare $_SERVER as a global to use it in a class method? Or can I just straight up use it without worrying about it.

Background: I'm converting part of our administrative dashboard into a class style architecture, from just having pages with script and DB calls on it, and one of the values plugged into this MySQL logging table is INET_ANON(%s) where %s is replaced with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. I just need to know if I can move that call directly into the data member, or if I have to do anything extra to make $_SERVER available for use there.

Thanks!
--Lisa

Comment: Why don't you try to use it and see what happens.

Comment: Because I don't have access to the test environment at the moment. It's being worked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_SERVER (as well as $_REQUEST, $_SESSION, $_POST, $_GET, etc...) is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), and they are visible in ALL scopes in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

$_SERVER is a global variable already defined. You don't have to define it. Just use it.

Comment: Right, but I wasn't sure if I had to do global $_SERVER at the top of my method, like I have to do with my database connection object.